# Why my node doesn't create any block?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, pallet-staking

I Added `pallet-staking` and it's build fine. When I'm running the node in dev mode using `./target/release/node-template --dev` this command, it doesn't create any blocks. Can someone point out me why block are not producing after adding `staking-pallet`.

This is terminal output.

[image]

Code is in [github](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/tree/staking-pallet-testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there isn't any genesis stakers.

No validators means no one to produce the block.

https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/fd6743b04455fbf1f2d0aaccf4885970d951076b/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L180

---

I suggest you always checking the Substrate example node first before asking the question.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e0059a416a5768e58765a49b33c21920c0b0eb9/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L315